# Add "hover" same function as "scroll"

Tags: javascript, scroll, hover

first sorry for the English.
I want to "hover" over the logo and do the same "scroll" function of the menu. How should it be?

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#nav');
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joselm65/x7k0phz5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply refactor the function out, and call it for both scroll and hover events:

```
// Write this below your current JS code
$('#logotipo').mouseenter(function(){
    nav.addClass('hidden');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    nav.removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).trigger('scroll');
});
```

Comment: Thank J.Ko, but I want the menu to appear with the hover, not hide it.
Sorry if I do not explain myself well.

Comment: can you explain more succinctly? like,
if(hover) ___(expected action)___
if(logo.click) ___(expected action)__

Comment: I want to put the mouse on the "logotipo" also appear the menu. And when removing the mouse disappear.

Comment: @joselm changed my answer. Please check if this solution is suitable for you.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Fantastic. Thank J.Ko